# How do you verify a SPNEGO token once it's generated in integration testing

Tags: integration-testing, kerberos, spnego, kdc

I have used the library **SimpleKdcServer** and created an intergation test which at the end produces a SPNEGO token. Is there a way to verify it, like can I somehow reverse the process and make sure that the genreated token is the correct value or format?

For now I have a check to verify it starts with "Negotiate" but is that enough, is there not a more robust way to do it like:

```
asserThat("Negotiate XfkeEmf34FNDM...").isEqualTo(someMethodToReverseToken())
```

Comment: Unless you can provide keytabs and DNS mapping for the integration tests, it won't work.

Comment: I have the keytabs and DNS which I create myself for the testing. Is there a reverse process I can do with this information to verify the token?

Comment: Since you have that, you need now to use JGSS to verify the token. That's it.